# React Typescript: SetState inside React.FC to change value in React.Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an `React.Component` with an state `modalVisible` to open an Modal:

```
<Modal
   visible={this.state.modalVisible}
>
   <FormStructure
      record={this.state.selectedRecord}
      question={this.state.question}
      dropdownItems={this.state.dropdownItems}
   />
</Modal>
```

After the `Modal` opens the `React.FC` `<FormStrucutre ... />` gets rendered and the Problem is that I dont know how to change the state value `modalVisible` inside the `React.FC`:

```
 const Submit = () => {
        fetch('api/Call/Save', {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'No': form.getFieldValue('no')
            })
        })
            .then(() => this.setState({modalVisible: false}); //TS2532  (TS) Object is possibly 'undefined'.
    };
```

Comment: Does this help ? this!.setState({modalVisible: false}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the closeModal method to `React.FC <FormStructure />`

```
// class component

<Modal
   visible={this.state.modalVisible}
>
   <FormStructure
      record={this.state.selectedRecord}
      question={this.state.question}
      dropdownItems={this.state.dropdownItems}
      closeModal={() => this.setState({modalVisible: false})}
   />
</Modal>
```

Use the props in FormStructure

```
// FormStructure.tsx

const FormStructure = (props: any) => {
  const {record, question, dropdownItems, closeModal} = props;

  const onSubmit = () => {
     ....
     closeModal();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern is to pass callbacks in as props, and child components call callbacks when events happen. In this case you could expose an `onSave` prop:

```
// parent
<Modal
   visible={this.state.modalVisible}
>
   <FormStructure
      record={this.state.selectedRecord}
      question={this.state.question}
      dropdownItems={this.state.dropdownItems}
      onSave={() => this.setState({modalVisible: false})}
   />
</Modal>


// child
class FormStructure extends React.Component {
   const Submit = () => {
        fetch('api/Call/Save', {
           // ...
        })
            .then(() => this.props.onSave();
    };
}
```